# Remove Null and empty values from json sink to blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure dataflow to read records from Azure SQL DB as source, modify it and write to blob storage as json file. I need only non-empty and -null values in JSON.

So, if source record is as below:

```
CustomerID, contact, age
10000, null, 45
10001, "", 35
10002, "7805289894", 38
```

JSON should be like:

```
[{"CustomerID": 10000, "age": 45}, {"CustomerID": 10001, "age": 35}, {"CustomerID": 10002, "contact": "7805289894", "age": 38}]
```

How can we achieve this in azure dataflow?

Please help solve this issue.

Comment: which coding Language you are using ? If Python then why not you handle it using GET function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple test, I think the result is what you want:
[image]

1. The source is Azure SQL. Azure data flow will filter Null property automatically when we sink files to json format. So in `DerivedColumn1` activity,we can use expression `case(length(contact)==0, toString(null()), contact)` to convert `''` to `null`.
   [image]
2. After `DerivedColumn1` activity, we can see non-empty and null values were converted to null values.
   [image]
3. The debugging result is as follows:
   [image]

Comment: Hi @Jesse , please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.